# Iframe with ruby in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, iframe, google-geocoder

I am used geocoder gem

How can i put iframe insted of image_tag ?

```
 <%= image_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=450x300&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{@presale.latitude}%2C#{@presale.longitude}", width: "300", height:"200" %>
```

I want the same code but with iframe please help me

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
<%= content_tag(:iframe,'', width: 300, height: 200, src: "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=450x300&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{@presale.latitude}%2C#{@presale.longitude}") %>
```

Comment: The src  have these #{@presale.latitude}%2C#{@presale.longitude}

Comment: @nour what is exactly not working? i dont know how you fill your presale class. the content_tag is working. it display's an iframe with the src

Comment: http://presalevancouver.herokuapp.com/presales/1 Its under the location map can you check ,its display a white space  instead,  It work in image_tag but not in content_tag